# Floating button over a fullscreen webview in Nativescript

Tags: layout, webview, containers, nativescript, floating

I'm very new to nativescript, and I'm lost with the container layout. How can I set a webview in fullscreen with 2 floating bottoms, over the webview, fixed at the bottom of the app ?

!https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrlNv.jpg

I tried at this time 2 solutions :

Can you help me please ?

- https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=QIXiNZ
  With this, the second element is at 60px height, and in CSS, I tried to translate it to top (-60px)... But it disappears behind webview.

```
<GridLayout rows="*,60">
    <WebView left="0" top="0" width="100%" height="100%" loaded="onWebViewLoaded"
        id="webViewID" width="100%" src="https://www.stackoverflow.com" />
    <AbsoluteLayout class="mywidget" row="1" orientation="horizontal">
        <Button class="btn-promo" text="Promos" left="0" bottom="0" height="55" />
        <Button class="btn-espacepro" text="Espace pro" right="10" bottom="0"
            height="55" />
    </AbsoluteLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

- https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=aPtpmB
  I tried to tweak it with html, position relative for the parent, position obsolute with bottom:0px to the Stacklayout with absolut-it class.

```
<GridLayout class="relative-it" rows="*">
    <ScrollView row="0">
        <WebView left="0" top="0" width="100%" height="100%" loaded="onWebViewLoaded"
            id="webViewID" width="100%" src="https://www.stackoverflow.com" />
    </ScrollView>
    <StackLayout class="absolute-it" row="1">
        <Button class="btn-promo" text="Promos" left="0" bottom="0" height="55" />
        <Button class="btn-espacepro" text="Espace pro" right="10" bottom="0"
            height="55" />
    </StackLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
<GridLayout rows="*,auto" columns="*,*">
    <WebView src="https://www.nativescript.org" colSpan="2" />
    <Button row="1" col="0" text="Button 1" class="btn btn-primary" />
    <Button row="1" col="1" text="Button 2" class="btn btn-primary" />
</GridLayout>
```

[Updated Playground](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=QIXiNZ&v=3)